# How to make the script press return with pynput

Tags: python

I just started learning python and I have made this script that types for me, but I couldn't figure out how to make it press the enter key.

````
import time

keyboard = Controller()

time.sleep(3)

for char in "Hello, this isn't notking but this is a bot, he has been learning python and learned this script that types for him!":
    keyboard.press(char)
    keyboard.release(char)
    time.sleep(0.12)```
````

Answer (score 1):

This should help you with your problem. Next time please provide the whole code related to the question.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

import time

keyboard = Controller()

time.sleep(3)

for char in "Hello, this isn't notking but this is a bot, he has been learning python and learned this script that types for him!":
    keyboard.press(char)
    keyboard.release(char)
    time.sleep(0.12)

keyboard.press(Key.enter)
keyboard.release(Key.enter)
```